# Get info from remote database without access to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, remote-server

I'm working with asp.net and I have a job where I have to extract data from a SQL server database on a remote server that won't allow access to it? What is the best way to get this data out and onto my site so I can query the tables.

EDIT:

So... I don't have access to the database. What about some sort of service or even extracting the data into files, that I can upload to the server and query like the database. That would work but is it possible.

Comment: Well if you can't access the database directly, what options _do_ you have?

Comment: haha, you asked me the same question. Like setting up some type of service? That's the thing, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yep. :) My point was that we don't know what you are permitted to do here. Will you be able to access the server locally? If so, perhaps you can set up a service, as you suggest, or perhaps something else - but that depends on several factors, such as what this data is, how big and complex it is, what format it is best represented in, etc. Could you provide some more details?

Answer (score 1):

1) Ask for permission to access the DB; or 2) Ask for an API (batch or real-time) to access the data.

Barring that, you will be unable to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what other options you have.  If you can add some more details it would be useful.

Ask for a database access – you only need datareader permission and you can also use views and/or set explicit permissions to further restrict the access rights

If that’s not possible for whatever reason you can try retrieving data through some reporting interface or API or some other custom solution.

Comment: Can you expand upon the reporting interface. I we can extract the data into files I can add to the site and then query like a database, that would work.